# XML post giving error in php

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

submitting xml data using post method but its giving following error

```
ASP 500 Error

An error occurred processing the page you requested.
Please see the details below for more information.
COM Error Number    -2146827864 (0x800A01A8)
File Name   /vm/VM_jeune/includes/partenaires_calcul_primes.asp
Line Number     110
Brief Description   Object required: 'objDOMXPCML.selectSingleNode(...)'
```

```
<?php
/* 
Online PHP Examples with Source Code
website: http://4evertutorials.blogspot.in/
*/
$xml_data ='<aatavailreq1>'.
    '<agency>'.
        '<iata>1234567890</iata>'.
        '<agent>lgsoftwares</agent>'.
        '<password>mypassword</password>'.
        '<brand>phpmind.com</brand>'.
    '</agency>'.
    '<passengers>'.
        '<adult age="" id="1"></adult>'.
        '<adult age="" id="2"></adult>'.
    '</passengers>'.
'<hotelavailreq1>'.
'<destcode>JHM</destcode>'.
        '<hotelcode>OGGSHE</hotelcode>'.
        '<checkindate>101009</checkindate>'.
        '<checkoutdate>101509</checkoutdate>'.
        '<usefield>1</usefield>'.
  '</hotelavailreq1>'.  
  '</aatavailreq1>';


$URL = "http://www.example.com/vm/makessense/calcul_primes.asp";

   $ch = curl_init($URL);
 //  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL );
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $output = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

 print_r($output);
?>
```

its giving 500 error not accepting any data please tell me what is the error in this code.

Comment: Look in the server's error log to see what error you are getting exactly.

Comment: here i don't have access to see server log because here we are submitting data to client server

Comment: add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in $xml_data

Comment: Either the remote app is broken (I would not expect too much from an ASP app that's still active in 2013) or, most likely, your XML code does not conform to the format that the remote API is expecting.

Comment: This the format i got it from client.

Answer (score 0):

An error 500 means that the program receiving the XML file has crashed. We can see that it has a bug because it isn't handling the error condition gracefully, but we can't see what that bug is, nor how it is affected by your input data because the ASP crash message has insufficient information to work it out.

So the basic answer to your question is: We don't know, and we can't tell. The only people who could tell you what the problem is would be the owners of the site that has crashed.

You could use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) to examine the HTTP traffic. This will help you to prove that your code is sending the XML string correctly. You could also use an XML validation tool to prove that the XML is valid.

But if those tests prove that it's okay at your end (and I suspect they will), then there's nothing much else you can do other than ask the people receiving the XML what's wrong with their software and how you can resolve the problem; it may need a code fix on their side, or they may be able to help you work around the issue. Either way, there's nothing we can do here to help you with it.